# Is the sentence "Il n'en a aucun parlé bien" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaire

Is the sentence "Il n'en a aucun parlé bien" grammatically correct?

I want to say "He spoke none of them (languages) well".

Comment: Il ne parle aucune correctement. Une langue, parler ***une langue***. Parler une langue does not take DE or A, and therefore, it does not take EN or Y. Aucune is enough.

Comment: @Lambie *Il ne parle aucune correctement* is missing something to be correct French.

Comment: @Lambie: "Il ne parle aucune correctement" should be "Il n'en parle aucune correctement".

Comment: @Frank Il parle cinq langues mais il ne parle aucune [langue] correctement.

Comment: @Lambie - vous pouvez parler comme vous voulez. Je continuerai a dire "Il parle cinq langues mais il **n'en** parle aucune correctement", qui sonne beaucoup mieux a mes oreilles françaises.

Comment: Il parle cinq langues, et ***de toutes ces langues***, il n'en parle aucune correctement. Lá, oui.

Comment: Got more confirmation from other native french speakers here (besides me): "Il parle cinq langues mais il ne parle aucune correctement." does not sound correct at all.

Answer (score 3):

No but you can say: "Il n'en parle aucune correctement"

Answer (score 2):

> *(**De** toutes les langues qu'il connaît,) il n'**en** parle aucune correctement* ( or *suffisamment bien.* )

or

> *Il ne parle aucune d'entre elles correctement.*

Comment: Evidemment, si vous dites DE TOUTES les langues, on mettrait en, mais qui dit qu'il faille dire cela? On pourrait tres bien ***dire***, il parle trois langues mais il ne parle aucune correctement.

Comment: @Lambie Je n'ai jamais entendu ou lu une tournure pareille. Ce qui est idiomatique, c'est « Il parle trois langues, mais aucune correctement » qui sous entend « Il parle trois langues, mais [ [il] n'en parle ] aucune correctement ».

Comment: Oui, c'est sous entendu. On tout cas, correctement est une faute. Il faut dire bien. Correctement is not correctly. sans faute [grammaticale].

Comment: @Lambie Oui, pourquoi pas « bien », j'ai d'ailleurs proposé « suffisamment bien » pour mieux coller à *well* mais la question ne porte pas la dessus et de toute façon, la nuance est très négligeable ici. S'il ne parle bien aucune des langues en question, il n'en parle forcément aucune correctement.

Answer (score -2):

Please note: to speak a language correctly is not correctement in French. That is a false friend. It's: parler sans faute [grammaticale], parler bien, bien parler or parler couramment. Correctement in French means WELL. Il parle anglais correctement: His English is fine, His English is not bad.

1) Il parle cinq langues et il ne parle aucune couramment ou bien.

2) De cinq langues qu'ils parlent, il n'en parle aucune couramment ou bien.

The passé composé does not work in this sentence. It has to be present, past or some other tense.

The English: /He spoke none of them well/ would be an imperfect in French, probably.

I heard him speaking the five languages and he **spoke** none of them well =
In French: Je lui ai entendu parler dans les cinq langues et  il ne parlait aucune [d'entre elles] bien ou sans faute.

OR: 
Je lui ai entendu parler dans cinq langues étrangères, il **n'en parlait** aucune bien ou sans faute.

Comment: On peut parler une langue correctement (c'est à dire sans faire de fautes) sans pour autant la parler couramment ; *a contrario* on peut parler une langue couramment sans pour autant la parler correctement (ce qui est le cas de bien des natifs autant en France qu'en pays anglophones).

Comment: No, if you say in ENGLISH, he speaks grammatically correctly, that is not correctement in French. It means: sans faute grammaticale. Je répète: correctement en français ne se traduit pas par correctly en anglais. Je donnais plusieurs options pour traduire les mots to speak correctly en français. Cela ne veut évidemment pas DIRE que c'est toujours couramment. C'était pour monter l'erreur de traduction.

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre pourquoi parler de faux amis entre *correctly* et *correctement* pour ensuite dire que *correctement* est une bonne traduction de *well*. *Well* est justement le seul adverbe que BlobGod a utilisé en anglais, adverbe qu'il a d'ailleurs correctement traduit par « bien ».

Comment: « Je **lui ai entendu parler dans** les cinq langues et il ne parlait aucune bien » est incorrect. C'est « Je **l'ai entendu parler dans** les cinq langues » voire « Je **lui ai entendu parler** cinq langues ».

Comment: @Lambie - pas sur que la différence soit aussi significative que vous le prétendez, entre "well", "correct", "bien" et "correctement". Par contre, je note de petites fautes dans les phrases que vous proposez: " Il parle cinq langues et il ne parle aucune couramment ou bien." sonne moins naturel que " Il parle cinq langues et il **n'en** parle aucune couramment, ou bien." et "De cinq langues qu'ils parlent" serait mieux écrit: "**Des** cinq langues qu'ils parlent..."

Comment: Personellement, je ne dirais jamais "sonne moins naturel que". Ce n'est pas une phrase idiomatique du tout. Qui l'aurait enlevée?? Je vois qu'elle n'est plus ici. Par ailleurs, je me suis trompée puisque je pensais que la phrase contenait: speak correctly. :)